# Can a server on the other end of a site-to-site vpn be exposed (NATd) to a public IP on an ASA

Tags: cisco-asa, vpn, nat

```
AWS                                      DataCenter
-----------        site-to-site VPN      ------------
http server   <=======================>  Cisco ASA   public address
10.0.1.59:443                                         109.1.2.27:8443
```

AWS VPC (with a web server) connects via a site-to-site VPN to DataCenter.  There is a public address on the outside of the ASA at DataCenter that I want to NAT the webserver in AWS to.  If the web server were inside the LAN behind DataCenter's ASA, this would be easy.  I do that already.  Basically I need to keep the public address of the server the same, but move it from the DataCenter to a branch office that's connected to DataCenter's ASA.

I've tried this:
`nat (outside,outside) source static 10.0.1.59 109.1.2.3 service http http8443`
but it doesn't work.

I do have same-security-traffic enabled.

```
same-security-traffic permit intra-interface
```

The ASA is version 9.9(2).

And no, I can't change the public IP and I can't move the IP to branch office.

Thanks in advance,

Edit: ASA config:

```
xlate per-session deny tcp any4 any4
xlate per-session deny tcp any4 any6
xlate per-session deny tcp any6 any4
xlate per-session deny tcp any6 any6
xlate per-session deny udp any4 any4 eq domain
xlate per-session deny udp any4 any6 eq domain
xlate per-session deny udp any6 any4 eq domain
xlate per-session deny udp any6 any6 eq domain

!
interface GigabitEthernet1/1
 nameif inside
 security-level 100
 ip address 192.168.2.98 255.255.255.0 
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/3
 nameif outside
 security-level 0
 ip address 109.1.2.26 255.255.255.248 
!
ftp mode passive
same-security-traffic permit inter-interface
same-security-traffic permit intra-interface

object network company-inside-datacenter
 subnet 192.168.2.0 255.255.255.0

object network webserver
 host 192.168.2.24

object network public-address
 host 109.1.2.27

object service https
 service tcp source eq https 

object service https8443
 service tcp source eq 8443 

object network obj-amzn
 subnet 10.0.0.0 255.255.0.0

object network obj_any
 subnet 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0

object network webserver-aws
 host 10.0.1.59

object-group network datacenter-etc
 network-object 192.168.2.0 255.255.255.0

access-list nonat extended permit ip any4 192.168.2.0 255.255.255.0 

access-list inside_access_in extended permit ip 192.168.2.0 255.255.255.0 any4 

access-list outside_access_in extended permit tcp any4 object webserver eq https 

access-list outside_access_in extended permit object https8443 any4 object webserver-aws 

access-list acl-amzn extended permit ip any4 10.0.0.0 255.255.0.0 

access-list inside_access_in_3 extended permit ip any4 any4 

nat (inside,any) source static any any destination static company-inside-datacenter company-inside-datacenter no-proxy-arp route-lookup

nat (inside,outside) source static webserver public-address service https https
nat (outside,outside) source static webserver-aws public-address service https https8443 no-proxy-arp

nat (inside,outside) source static company-inside-datacenter company-inside-datacenter destination static group-remote-aws group-remote-aws no-proxy-arp route-lookup
nat (outside,outside) source static datacenter-etc datacenter-etc destination static obj-amzn obj-amzn no-proxy-arp route-lookup
nat (inside,outside) source static datacenter-etc datacenter-etc destination static obj-amzn obj-amzn no-proxy-arp route-lookup

object network company-inside-datacenter
 nat (outside,outside) dynamic interface

object network obj_any
 nat (inside,outside) dynamic interface

access-group inside_access_in_3 in interface inside
access-group outside_access_in in interface outside
access-group global_access global

route outside 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 109.1.2.25 1

sysopt connection tcpmss 1300
service sw-reset-button

crypto ipsec security-association pmtu-aging infinite
crypto dynamic-map outside_dyn_map 20 set ikev1 transform-set ESP-AES256-SHA1_TRANS ESP-AES128-SHA1_TRANS ESP-AES256-SHA1

crypto map outside_map 300 match address acl-amzn
crypto map outside_map 300 set pfs 
crypto map outside_map 300 set peer 53.53.53.27 53.53.53.32 
crypto map outside_map 300 set ikev1 transform-set transform-amzn
crypto map outside_map 300 set security-association lifetime seconds 3600
crypto map outside_map 300 set reverse-route
crypto map outside_map 65535 ipsec-isakmp dynamic outside_dyn_map
crypto map outside_map interface outside
management-access inside
no vpn-addr-assign dhcp
vpn-addr-assign local reuse-delay 1
dhcprelay timeout 60
group-policy DfltGrpPolicy attributes
 vpn-tunnel-protocol ikev1 l2tp-ipsec ssl-clientless

group-policy AmznGrpPolicy internal
group-policy AmznGrpPolicy attributes
 vpn-idle-timeout 30
 vpn-session-timeout none
 vpn-filter none
 vpn-tunnel-protocol ikev1 
 split-tunnel-all-dns disable

dynamic-access-policy-record DfltAccessPolicy

tunnel-group 53.53.53.27 type ipsec-l2l
tunnel-group 53.53.53.27 general-attributes
 default-group-policy AmznGrpPolicy
tunnel-group 53.53.53.27 ipsec-attributes
 ikev1 pre-shared-key *******************
 isakmp keepalive threshold 10 retry 3
 ikev2 remote-authentication pre-shared-key *******************
 ikev2 local-authentication pre-shared-key *******************

tunnel-group 53.53.53.32 type ipsec-l2l
tunnel-group 53.53.53.32 general-attributes
 default-group-policy AmznGrpPolicy
tunnel-group 53.53.53.32 ipsec-attributes
 ikev1 pre-shared-key *******************
 isakmp keepalive threshold 10 retry 3
 ikev2 remote-authentication pre-shared-key *******************
 ikev2 local-authentication pre-shared-key *******************

!
class-map inspection_default
 match default-inspection-traffic
!
!
policy-map type inspect dns preset_dns_map
 parameters
  message-length maximum client auto
  message-length maximum 4096
  no tcp-inspection
policy-map global_policy
 class inspection_default
  inspect dns preset_dns_map 
  inspect ftp 
  inspect h323 h225 
  inspect h323 ras 
  inspect rsh 
  inspect rtsp 
  inspect esmtp 
  inspect sqlnet 
  inspect skinny  
  inspect sunrpc 
  inspect xdmcp 
  inspect sip  
  inspect netbios 
  inspect tftp 
  inspect ip-options 
 class class-default
  user-statistics accounting
!
service-policy global_policy global
```

This is a very stripped down/sanitized config with all addresses/names changed and lots of unrelated VPN tunnels removed.

The current server that's NAT'd to the public-address is "webserver".  The new server that I need to NAT to the same thing is "webserver-aws" (a server inside an AWS VPC that's connected to the ASA via the Site-Site VPN).  I'm trying to set it up concurrently to test, so current server is exposing tcp443 as tcp443 and my test entry is trying to expose the new server on tcp8443 for testing.

Edit 2:

After trying @Ricky's answer with and without no-proxy-arp, this is my packet tracer result:

`packet-tracer input outside tcp 0.0.0.1 1 109.1.2.27 8443 detailed`
gave this

```
Phase: 1
Type: ROUTE-LOOKUP
Subtype: Resolve Egress Interface
Result: ALLOW
Config:
Additional Information:
found next-hop 109.1.2.27 using egress ifc  outside

Result:
input-interface: outside
input-status: up
input-line-status: up
output-interface: outside
output-status: up
output-line-status: up
Action: drop
Drop-reason: (nat-no-xlate-to-pat-pool) Connection to PAT address without pre-existing xlate
```

Comment: I'm trying to understand what you're asking. Are you saying you want a server physically at the branch office that's connected to the data center over a site-to-site tunnel to be NATed to a public IP address assigned to the data center? Like you want public internet requests to come in to the data center, to then go over the tunnel to reach the server?

Comment: We need to see the ASA configuration. Can the server reach the Internet ( outbound)?

Comment: @RonTrunk I'm anxious to see if what I understand the question to be is correct.  You'd have to set the default route or gateway on the host to be something in the data center, and I can't see that working too great when you need to access the host locally but from a different network.  You'd have static routes all over the place to hack this together.

Comment: You not only need to DNAT the public address at the datacenter, you also need to make sure that the remote server's replies are going *back into the VPN tunnel* (e.g. using policy-based routing).

Comment: @Zac67 If we're even correctly assuming this is what the OPs question even was, that's part of the problem unless they just want all inbound and outbound internet traffic involving this host to go out the data center's connction, because otherwise they'll be using PBR for return traffic out the data center's internet connection, and local internet access for things like updates and such.  That's just ugly.

Comment: @JesseP. Agreeing completely, but the OP seems to be in a bind...

Comment: @Zac67 I know.  I just want them to confirm that's even the correct goal before we start coming up with solutions.

Comment: @JesseP. : Yes, that's exactly what I need.  I have a single purpose server that's currently in the DataCenter that's exposed as a public IP (DataCenter owned).  I have users of that server that require it to be accessed at that public IP address (due to firewall rules, which will take me a year to get changed, if I'm lucky).  I need to relocate that server from behind the ASA at the DataCenter to the branch office.  I can route all traffic from that server back through the Site-To-Site tunnel if needed.  I control the branch office, site-to-site tunnel and the ASA in the datacenter.

Comment: @ChrisHolt Okay. Thanks for confirming.  Can you provide a sanitized config for the ASA?  What is the branch office using for the internet edge or whatever you're terminating the tunnel to?

Comment: What you need is "twice nat" -- rewrite src and dst. I've done that for a few reasons locally, but it took a day of different configs to get it working correctly. (it's ugly) If I can find the archive of that config, I'll post it.

Comment: @JesseP. Sanitized config posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
object network obj-SERVER
 host <SERVER>
!
object network obj_any
 subnet 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0
!
object service dest-tcp-REAL
 service tcp destination eq <REAL> 
object service dest-tcp-MAPPED
 service tcp destination eq <MAPPED> 
!
nat (outside,inside) source static obj_any interface destination static interface obj-SERVER service dest-tcp-MAPPED dest-tcp-REAL unidirectional no-proxy-arp
```

That maps the outside interface address to an inside server, and changes the source to the inside interface so the traffic will return to the same firewall. If the outside IP isn't the firewall's interface, you'll need an additional host object to replace the first "interface" (source). Internal routing should handle it from there, but there may be some crazy required. (I have "nat 0" rules as well, but my vpn setup is not normal.)

This worked for me to map a serial console port through a backup link that would not otherwise be the return path for that traffic.

[ASA 9.1(7)32]

Comment: That's exactly what they're asking; users must connect to that **server** public IP... If the remote site *is not* contained to the VPN, then this is what is needed. The server's default gateway (and associated kit) rarely send the return traffic back along the same path (asymmetric routing), so the original FW holding the NAT entry doesn't handle the replies. Correct the routing and simple NAT is all that's needed -- exactly the same as before the move, just with a different inside address. (the hairpin can be it's own issue.)

Comment: A sends to B who rewrites it to go to X. Any reply will be X to A; X doesn't know about B. If the X>A path doesn't flow back through B, X won't be rewritten back to B, and the whole thing falls apart. There are two ways to fix that: (1) fiddle with routing to make X>A go through B, or (2) rewrite A so the traffic looks like it came from B, and thus will always come back to B. Option 1 is policy-based routing; a slow, expensive process on most hardware, and an annoying surprise to the next admin. Option 2 is problem for security as the server no longer knows the true origin of the traffic.

Comment: Site-to-site VPN. Yes, I'm assuming the VPN works. The above changes src **and** dst, so the server sees the FW as the source, not the internet user. Thus, the reply will go back to the FW so long as the VPN works.

Comment: @Ricky, I've configured your suggestion with no luck thus far.  And as you suggested, I replaced the first "interface" with a host object for the outside IP since the public IP is not the ASA's external interface. (it's the external IP +1 in this case).  Any suggestions on ASA capture/debug commands to diagnose where it's failing?

Comment: `packet-tracer`

Comment: @Ricky: why is this "nat (outside,inside)" instead of "nat (inside,outside)".  All of my other NAT rules for exposing servers that are inside the data center are "nat (inside,outside)".  Also, why unidirectional?  And packet-tracer is, thus far, not very helpful.  It ended with "nat-no-xlate-to-pat-pool"..

Comment: @ChrisHolt The interfaces in a NAT statement are in the order of ingress and then egress (for example, with the NAT statement Ricky gave, traffic comes in the outside, goes out the inside).  As for the unidirectional flag, NAT statements are bidirectional by default; unidirectional makes the statement only take effect in the direction the interfaces are listed in, and not the inverse as well.  Finally, for the packet-tracer part - can you post the full packet-tracer output along with what exactly you typed in so we can where it's getting hung up at?

Comment: We normally define nat as inside-to-outside, and get the out-to-in "for free". In this specific case, the rule is to turn internet traffic into internal traffic [out-to-in] and you very much DO NOT want that applied in reverse, because it's an "any" match, it will mess with all outbound traffic. It took several hours of breaking the network to get this working.

Comment: Now that I'm thinking about it, the `no-proxy-arp` may be a problem for you, as the FW needs to answer for an address that isn't assigned to an interface. But the outside match is "any", so enabling proxy-arp will have the FW answering for everything on the outside. (I had to watch external traffic to catch it.)

Comment: @Ricky Usually the only time proxy-ARP needs to be disabled on NAT statements is if you use "any" for either of the interfaces, to make sure that the statement only comes into play with your desired traffic. Since you have the interfaces defined for both ingress and egress, you shouldn't need to disable proxy-ARP.

Comment: @JesseP., question edited above with packet tracer output.

Comment: @JesseP. also I should mention that "show nat" shows 0 counts for translate and un-translate for the nat rule, so it's not even being hit.

Comment: @ChrisHolt Part of the problem is that you didn't use a real IP address for your source.  Just use something like 8.8.8.8 and then 1234 for the source port.  The rest looked fine.

Comment: @JesseP. I tried a real IP for the source 199.233.121.111.  same result.

Comment: @ChrisHolt Can you show me what the NAT statement looks like after you modified it from what Ricky gave as an example?

Comment: @JesseP. nat (outside,inside) source static obj_any public-address destination static interface webserver-aws service https8443 https8443 unidirectional.  To try and simplify things, I kept the port 8443 all the way through.  public-address is 109.1.2.27.  webserver-aws is 10.0.1.59.

Comment: I finally got this to work. With 1 addition.

    object network obj-fake-source
     host <unused-address-inside-asa>
   And 1 tweak. 
    nat (outside,outside) source static obj_any obj-fake-source destination static interface obj-SERVER service dest-tcp-MAPPED dest-tcp-REAL unidirectional no-proxy-arp